# How does Copy-on-Write (CoW) work when using the new pandas pyarrow backend?

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I think the question says it all — the pandas docs have good information on both the new [CoW behavior](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/copy_on_write.html) and the [pyarrow backend](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html), but was wondering if CoW works the same with pyarrow as it does with a numpy backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of using facing behaviour, it should work the same. The new Copy-on-Write rules (modification of one DataFrame/Series object doesn't affect any other pandas object) will work the same with pyarrow-backed data types.

However, because of pyarrow arrays being immutable, you are less likely to run into copy/view issues (depending on the kind of operation). And we should also ensure that we don't needlessly trigger copies for pyarrow-backed columns when not needed because of this immutability (this might not yet be implement as efficient as possible, as of pandas 2.1.0).